# Java string normalization

Tags: java, normalization

Is there a Java library to normalize a string by removing spaces/special characters, lowercase all letters, for example: `S-cube Abc' Inc.` to `scubeabcinc`?

Comment: `s = s.replaceAll("\\W", "").toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 6):

There is **`java.text.Normalizer`**. Java holds text in Unicode, and `é` can be written as one Unicode symbol, code point, or as two, an `e` and a zero-width `'`. Unicode normalisation is very important, for dictionaries, file names.
The Normalizer can be used to decompose into letters and accents (diacritical marks), and with a **regex `replaceAll`** remove all accents.

**`Character`** has Unicode support giving Unicode names to code points, classifying code points as letters, digits, several scripts etcetera.

There is **`Collate`**, Locale oriented, that creates specific keys for words, for ordering, as `Comparator`. In one locale the order could be AaBbCcĉD.. and in another ABC...abc and such. `Locale` specifies toUpperCase. For instance in Turkish there is a letter i-without-dot `Iı` and i-with-dot `İi`.

And then there is your use-case: a reduction. There is for instance the *soundex* algorithm (third party) for sound-alike representation. Regex can remove interpunction etcetera with `String.replaceAll`.

Comment: You have summed it up quite well. OP should clarify his use case a little more, probably he needs to handle all this complexity.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a library other than String, `String.replaceAll` and `String.toLowerCase` does what you're looking for:

```
  String s = "S-cube Abc' Inc.";
  s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "").toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

No library is needed. Just use regex and [`String#toLowerCase`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase--):

```
String s = "S-cube Abc' Inc.";
s = s.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z]", "");
s = s.toLowerCase();
System.out.println(s);
```